# У меня возникла проблема в моем IOS приложение, а точнее в тексте кнопки. Текст кнопки написан слово под словом, а мне нужно чтобы слова были по центр

Tags: ios, xcode, button, mobile-development, storyboard

Вот скриншот storyboard
[image: текст под друг другом]

Вот скриншот ViewController
[image: я написал строку которая должна централизовать текст]
помогите решить проблему.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1.[как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)